# Resolving current user in UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal

Some basic informations about the UWP:

- Capabilities turned on: Internet (Client), User Account Information, Webcam
- No declarations
- Target version: Windows 10 Anniversary Edition
- Min Version: Windows 10 (10.0)
- Build Platform: x64

Here is my code to retrieve user informations:

```
public async Task ResolveUserAsync()
{
    if (_currentUserInfo != null)
    {
        return;
    }
    var users = await User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser);
    var desiredProperties = new[]
    {
        KnownUserProperties.FirstName, KnownUserProperties.LastName, KnownUserProperties.ProviderName, KnownUserProperties.AccountName, KnownUserProperties.GuestHost,
        KnownUserProperties.PrincipalName, KnownUserProperties.DomainName, KnownUserProperties.SessionInitiationProtocolUri
    };
    _currentUserInfo = await users.FirstOrDefault().GetPropertiesAsync(desiredProperties);
    foreach (var prop in _currentUserInfo)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{prop.Key}: {prop.Value}");
    }
}
```

The output in Debug console:

```
lastName:
firstName:
accountName: 
domainName: 
providerName: 
sipUri: 
principalName: 
guestHost:
```

The app runs on a tablet which is member of a classic AD and I cannot figure out, why those values are empty. The app asks for confirmation on user details in the UI.

Side notes: If I test this on a machine where I'm logged in with an AzureAD account this code will fill in `firstName` and `lastName` only.

Comment: Did you figure this out finally? I am having a similar problem and would like to know. thanks

Comment: @slayernoah Not yet. I'm on this issue still. I'll come back with infos.

Answer (score 1):

not fully sure if this behavior changed recently but in the past it was depending on your privacy settings as user (settings -> privacy -> account info -> the top toggle switch)

Comment: I checked this and the switch is on.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in my App.
After I turned on the "Enterprise Authentication" Feature in the app manifest, at least the principalName property was filled